How to add an image to Balsamiq with its native resolution?
I have an image that I want to put into a Balsamiq project. It's a UI reference image. It's important that it be high fidelity. I know this is contrast to Balsimiq's primary usage as a mockup tool, but in this case, this is a UX design artifact and we want to keep it in the same place as all our other UX design artifacts (Balsamiq).
This is what the image actually looks like:

This is what it looks like after importing into Balsamiq:

I've tried various ways of importing (drag and dropping the file, dragging in an image object into the project and double-clicking to load source image), I've tried scaling it, zooming in and out, have dug around for any relevant settings and turned up nothing. Google doesn't turn up anyone complaining about this issue, so I feel like I must be doing something wrong.
How do I add an image to a Balsamiq project so that it isn't turned into a blurry mess?
